# Вывод и отображение цвета из xml файла

Tags: php, xml

Есть xml файл:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<workers>
<worker>
  <name>Ivan</name>
  <color>Tomato</color>
</worker>
</workers>
```

И есть php файл:

```
  <?php
     $xml = simplexml_load_file("worrrkers.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

     foreach($xml->children() as $worrrkers) { 
        echo $worrrkers->name . "<br> "; 
        echo $worrrkers->color . "<hr> "; 
     }
  ?>
```

Как вывести на экран имя работника цветом указанным в xml? По его html имени или по коду, н-р  #0040ff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В поле Color вписываешь #0040ff, А на экран выводишь следующим образом:

```
echo '<span style="color:'.$worrrkers->color.'">'.$worrrkers->name.'</span>';
```

Comment: Именные цвета тоже работают

Comment: @Walfter, не отрицаю. Но на практике всё таки используют именно HEX, RGB или RGBA.